# Tizen Web Application Wearable :TypeMismatchError

Tags: javascript, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app

Getting a `TypeMismatchError: Value is not Object` in the following codes

```
var fileHandler = {
    storages:null,
    documentsDIR:null,
    newFile:null,
    dirName:"documents",
    fileName:"test.csv",
    init: function init(){
        //tizen.filesystem.listStorages(this.checkCorruptedRemovableDrives);documents
        tizen.filesystem.resolve(this.dirName, this.resolveSuccessCB,this.resolveErrorCB,"rw");

    },

    resolveSuccessCB: function resolveSuccessCB(result){
        this.documentsDir = result;
        //this.newFile = documentsDir.createFile(this.fileName);
        // Error Here - TypeMismatchError: Value is not Object
        result.listFiles(this.listFilesSuccessCB);
        console.log("All Good in "+this.documentsDir);
    },

    resolveErrorCB: function resolveErrorCB(error){
        console.log("Unable to access "+this.dirName+". Error:"+error.message);
    },

    listFilesSuccessCB: function listFilesSuccessCB(files){ 
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
          /* Display the file name and URI */
          console.log("File name is " + files[i].name + ", URI is " + files[i].toURI());
       }
    },



    onStorage: function onStorage(storage){ 
           console.log("Storage found:" + storage.label);
    },
    checkCorruptedRemovableDrives: function checkCorruptedRemovableDrives(storages){
        this.storages = storages;
        for (var i = 0; i < storages.length; i++) 
        { 
            if (storages[i].type != "EXTERNAL"){
                continue;
            }
            if (storages[i].state == "UNMOUNTABLE"){
                console.log("External drive " + storages[i].label + " is corrupted.");
            } else {
                console.log(" Storage = " + storages[i].label );
                // Error here - TypeMismatchError: Value is not Object
                tizen.filesystem.getStorage(storages[i].label, this.onStorage);
            }
        }
    }
```

};

The error occurs at two places marked as *Error Here* in the codes.

In `tizen.filesystem.getStorage(storages[i].label, this.onStorage);` the datatype of the first argument is DOMString and `storages[i].label` is also of type DOMString.
In `result.listFiles(this.listFilesSuccessCB);` expects a callback fucntion.

Most of the codes have been copied pasted from [Tizen FileSystem Guide](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/tutorials/web-application/tizen-features/base/filesystem?langredirect=1) but still not working.

Please help. Thank in advance!!
Also where can I find the "documents" directory, when I browse the filesystem of my wearable device.

Comment: Please give more details code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Answer change `this` to `fileHandler`.

Do not trust "this" when your function is called in tizen API.

You seems to use `checkCorruptedRemovableDrives` to succuess call back of `tizen.filesystem.listStorages`.

And you trust "this" in `checkCorruptedRemovableDrives` is `fileHandler`.

But most of Tizen web API callback functions called like following code.

```js
callback.apply(callback, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
```

first argument of apply is passed into `callback` for `this` but it is self function object.

So if you want `fileHandler` in your function, don't use `this` use fileHandler direct.

following code is Tizen web API implementation You can look `this` following `callIfPossible` function.

```js
function listStorages() {
  xwalk.utils.checkPrivilegeAccess(xwalk.utils.privilege.FILESYSTEM_READ);
  var args = validator_.validateArgs(arguments, [
    {name: 'onsuccess', type: types_.FUNCTION},
    {name: 'onerror', type: types_.FUNCTION, optional: true, nullable: true}
  ]);

  setTimeout(function() {
    var storages = [];
    var cache = commonFS_.getAllStorages();
    for (var i = 0; i < cache.length; ++i) {
      storages.push(new FileSystemStorage(cache[i]));
    }

    native_.callIfPossible(args.onsuccess, storages);
  }, 0);
};
```

https://review.tizen.org/git/?p=platform/core/api/webapi-plugins.git;a=blob;f=src/filesystem/js/file_system_manager.js;h=622f38d479647584012925773d124d7f9a59e51d;hb=refs/heads/tizen#l158

```js
NativeManager.prototype.callIfPossible = function(callback) {
  if (!_type.isNullOrUndefined(callback)) {
    callback.apply(callback, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
  }
};
```

https://review.tizen.org/git/?p=platform/core/api/webapi-plugins.git;a=blob;f=src/utils/utils_api.js;h=5502e3f2a46254c7e2da9d838bacd55be9aaab20;hb=refs/heads/tizen#l1141

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. I had figured out that. Had commented in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can get help from Tizen IDE online Sample App. 
You will be helped by [File Manager App](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/sample/web/Storage/File_Manager) of Tizen Web App.

And check [Filesystem API](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/guides/web-application/tizen-features/base/filesystem?langredirect=1) of Tizen. 
To get File Manager Online Sample,

- Go to New Web Project
- Online Sample
- Find File Manager

Demo: 
[image]

Comment: I am trying to perform the job on a wearable device Samsung Gear S2 classic. It does not work on the emulator either. I have also gone through the FileSystem API for Wearables and the above code are 90% copy paste form FileSystem Guide provided here :https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/tutorials/web-application/tizen-features/base/filesystem?langredirect=1

Still I will try and take a look at the above sample application. Hope it will help.

Comment: API is almost same i think. You can use this for getting help.

Comment: I found a solution, but I am not sure of what is the reason behind it.
the places where i get error, I make a call to those function using `this.functionName` The error was due to use of `this`. Once I removed `this` keword and replaced them with `fileHandler` things worked fine. Since I am not very much confident with javascript, I am unable assert the reason for such a behaviour, but still I guess its like using static context as in java or C